# AWS S3 files uploaded partially

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am using AWS JavaScript SDK 2 to upload files from my Webapplication. While uploading a large no files like 200 or more its showing success but files were not displayed in AWS consoles, many files were missing.

I am also making a head-object call to verify if file is uploaded successfully or not, which is giving success but still files are missing. Below is my code

```
// Upload file
const params = {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: directory + fileName,
  Body: file,
};
await s3Client.upload(params).promise();

// Check if uploaded successfully
const headParams = {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: directory + fileName,
};
const fileDetails = await s3Client.headObject(headParams).promise();
if (fileSize === fileDetails.ContentLength) {
  // Uploaded successfuly
}
```

is there anything I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is showing success? Your code, as shown, doesn't emit any results.

Comment: After the upload call, I am calling headObject, the head object will only work if file is there

Comment: Hi @Jamod, I am using that headObject method response to mark the upload success or failed